# Solving the inequalities $-3 \leq x^3 - 8x \leq 3$.

Tags: inequality

Can someone give me a hint on how to find $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$-3 \leq x^3 - 8x \leq 3?$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equality holds for $x=3$ and $x=-3$

Now the derivative of the function $x^3-8x$ is $3x^2-8$

Check when the derivative is positive and when it is negative(function increasing or decreasing) and draw the graph accordingly, you will get your solution!

Or you may basically solve two equations

$x^3-8x-3\leq0$ and $x^3-8x+3\geq0$

Also you know that $x-3$ is a factor of the first and $x+3$ is a factor of the second, so you are left with two quadratics and you can easily know when they are less than $0$ and when they are greater than $0$, so can you get the set of solutions for both the equations and take their intersection to get the final ans!!

Answer (score 1):

You could sketch the graph $y=x^3-8x = x(x^2-8)$ and look at values of $x$ such that the graph is between $y=-3$ and $y=3$.